# Meaning of a name in braces as a type hint

Tags: python, types

I have recently met the following method declaration (using the QuickDoc feature of Pycharm):

```
def save_weights(self,
                 filepath: {endswith},
                 overwrite: bool = True,
                 save_format: Optional[{__eq__}] = None) -> None
```

What is the meaning of `filepath: {endswith}` part, i.e. when some name in braces is given as a type hint? I have looked at the  [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) documentation but did not find reference to this syntax. Maybe this is only some artifact of Pycharm's Quickdoc feature?

Comment: Looks like "an object having an attribute named `endswith`".